# Как сделать колонки между блоками?

Tags: css, html

как сделать такие вот колонки между блоками?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависит от того, каким образом вы меню своё "строите".. Выложите хоть код, за вас это вряд ли кто-то писать будет.. Подобное можно просто `border`'ом сделать, можно через `list-style` сделать...

Answer (score 0):

Нуу.. есть много вариантов такое сделать, одно из самых простых - добавить обычный бордер справа от каждого блока и убрать этот бордер у крайнего элемента справа. HTML-style будет в приоритете:

```css
.moo {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  width: 20%; 
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo" style="border-right: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Можно было у общего блока сделать `background-color: black;` а между кнопками меню сделать зазор через `margin-right: 2px;`. Пустота между ними оказалась бы черной от бекграунда родителя.